# what is @,: in JSF

Tags: jsf

I have few doubts on JSF

1. @this, @form and :form space with  id of panel/row etc. What meant these attributes? When would be use these attributes in jsf?
2. In rendered attribute, can I check Application constants using primefaces extensions?
   For example:

   public class AppsUIConstants{

   public static final String UI_DAILY="Daily";
   }

and used primefaces extensiosn import constants

```
<pe:importConstants className="com.core.util.AppsUIConstants" var="AppConstants" />
```

But how can I check above constants at rendered attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For @:

```
@all - every component is executed
@form- The form which contains the component is processed
@none- No component is executed
@this- This is default. Requesting component is processed
```

You can find useful information at 
    http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Common_Ajax_attributes.html

See [How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-reference-components-in-jsf-ajax-cannot-find-component-with-identifier)

@BalusC has given a great explanation here.